# WMI not working in Logout event of Windows Service

Tags: c#, wmi

I have made a Windows Service to get user's information about login, logout, lock and unlock of the computer.
I used `WMI` to get user's information like name etc.
The Service works fine in login, lock and unlock but it can't get username from WMI in the Logout event.

How can I find `username` in the logout event?

My Code is:

```
switch (changeDescription.Reason)
{
    case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogon:
        string username = Machine.getInstance().getUsername();
        mode = Convert.ToInt32(CommonModule.sessionEvents.Logon);                            
        break;
    case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogoff:
        string username = Machine.getInstance().getUsername();
        mode = Convert.ToInt32(CommonModule.sessionEvents.Logout);                           
        break;
    case SessionChangeReason.SessionLock:
        string username = Machine.getInstance().getUsername();
        mode = Convert.ToInt32(CommonModule.sessionEvents.Lock);                            
        break;
    case SessionChangeReason.SessionUnlock:  
        string username = Machine.getInstance().getUsername();  
        mode = Convert.ToInt32(CommonModule.sessionEvents.UnLock);                            
        break;
    default:                           
        break;
}
```